# How to connect user to voice channel?

Tags: python-3.x, bots, discord.py

Is there a way to connect user(not bot) to a voice channel, even if he is not connected to any voice channel?

I have already tried user.move_to(channel) but this only works when user is already connected to some voice channel.

I expect connecting an user to voice channel, although he wasn't connected to any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible.

From docs:

[Moves a member to a new voice channel (they must be connected first).](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.move_to)

It's not the API but the Discord devs themselves who disabled this, probably to avoid abuse of the function.